# Ring -3 exploits and existence of other rings

Tags: exploit, hardware, research, intel, arm

### Concept of Rings

[image: x86 rings]Rings were introduced in the forerunner of UNIX, Multics, and had [8 rings](https://multicians.org/multics-data-security.html) for reading, writing, executing and calling ***(I don't quite understand why it needed 8 rings to do this, if anybody does consider that a bonus question!)***.  The x86 architecture by Intel incorporated the idea of rings into hardware, with 4 rings corresponding to ring 0 being for the kernel, 1 and 2 for device drivers, and 3 for applications.

### Situation in 2019

Ring 0 and 3 are typically the only ones used in modern x86 operating systems for most users, with ring 0 being reserved for kernel-level operations and ring 3 for user-level, although there are some exceptions; for example, [VirtualBox uses ring 1](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#swvirt-details) to allow the use of virtual hosts.  Generally, code in ring 3 can't access memory or operations in ring 0, although that was at the root of issues from Spectre and Meltdown disclosed in January 2018.

'Ring -1' has also been introduced for hypervisors - Intel VT-X and AMD-V add 9 machine code instructions, introducing the concept of ring -1.  Ring -2 is typically called SMM (system management mode) and is used for very low level operations such as power management and used only by system firmware.  It has been used with multiple exploits for rootkits to reside in without the operating system being able to interefere.

'Ring -3' was coined for levels operating below that after an attack was demonstrated by Invisible Things on the Intel Q35 chipset (fixed in Q45 and later).  This worked by remapping the first 16 MB of RAM reserved for the Intel Management Engine and operated even with a device in an S3 state.

ARM processors seem to use only 3 rings, ordered the other way around; PL0 being user, PL1 being operating system, PL2 being hypervisor.  [See Figure 3.20 and this page from ARM.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0425/BABCDDJG.html)

### Summary and question

There have been several exploits over the years demonstrating exploits on rings outside those originally described by the x86 architecture. **What would an even lower-level ring look like** (ring -4 in Intel, PL3 in ARM, or ring -3 in AMD) and **has there has been any work regarding exploits in this area**.  Additionally, I've tried to follow the [guide on good suggestive questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) so that explanations on the 'how' and 'why' are applicable.

Comment: Note that the negative rings are not _real_ rings. They were just given that nickname. A real ring is a value of CPL (Current Privilege Level), which cannot be negative. There's CPL0, CPL1, CPL2, and CPL3, and nothing else.

Comment: I think ring 2 was also used for OS/2 drivers.

Answer (score 5):

Negative rings are false rings. They are not actual privilege levels of the CPU. The way rings work is simple. Some instructions have privilege checks where they verify that the current privilege level, or CPL, is sufficient and if it is not, the instruction fails with a [general protection fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault). CPL0 is ring 0, CPL1 is ring 1, etc. Some instructions will require a certain privilege level depending on the value of its operands (for example, `mov` may return a GPF if the CPL is insufficient and the memory address given to it requires ring 0 to access, or if a register given to it is privileged). Others always require a higher privilege level. Still others can be configured to require CPL0. An example of that is the [`RDTSC`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_278.html) instruction. It will throw a general protection fault unless *either* the TSD bit in CR4 (the fourth [control register](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86#Control_Registers)) is unset, or the current privilege level is zero, or the system is in real mode (determined by checking if the PE bit in CR0 is unset). This instruction is internally defined as:

```
if(CR4.TSD == 0 || CPL == 0 || CR0.PE == 0) EDX:EAX = TimeStampCounter;
else Exception(GP(0));
```

I wrote a bit more about rings and their uses [in this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175826/106285).

There is no such thing as a negative privilege level. They don't exist. Ring -1 is merely a nickname for hypervisor functionality (VT-x on Intel). Ring -2 is a nickname for [System Management Mode](http://rcollins.org/ddj/Jan97/Jan97.html) context, or SMM, which executes isolated code when a special interrupt called an SMI occurs. Ring -3 is a nickname for the code that runs on the CSME, an i486/i586 hybrid co-processor inside modern Intel chipsets that, indirectly, has access to system memory (I say indirectly because it's not *designed* for full memory access, but it does expose a virtual PCIe device, and [it turns out](https://twitter.com/_markel___/status/898631448361652228) that it can also interfere with [DMAR](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-virtualization-technology-for-directed-io-vt-d-enhancing-intel-platforms-for-efficient-virtualization-of-io-devices), used by the IOMMU). Using protection rings as an analogy for these super-privileged contexts can be helpful, but the analogy breaks down when you start looking at x86 in detail.

---

> What would an even lower-level ring look like

The only thing that could be thought of as lower than any of these is called *probe mode* (which is, again, not a real ring). It is initiated by [JTAG](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-system-studio-2014-jtag-debugger-supports-more-processor-families) and provides an extreme amount of control over the entire CPU. Probe mode is not nearly as powerful as it used to be, but there may be ways to unlock a more powerful version of probe mode with access to special Intel hardware and credentials.

> has there has been any work regarding exploits in this area

Not really. JTAG requires physical access and, for Intel, a [password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gzwi.jpg) specific to the CPU's serial number. It's also possible that modern commercial Intel chipsets have JTAG and related debugging features disabled on non-development boards by burning specific OTP (one-time programmable) fuses built into the chipset. Someone more familiar with Intel may be able to clarify.

Comment: The JTAG password requirement is optional/vendor specific, none of the chips I have used required a JTAG password.

Comment: @markus-nm Non-development Intel boards typically require a JTAG password.

Comment: But JTAG is not limited to Intel chips. Virtually all ARM cortex chips are using JTAG and/or SWD. Most of them can be password protected, but none of them require that.

Comment: @markus-nm You're right. I was only thinking about Intel. I'll edit.

Comment: Agreed. Negative rings are an analogy at best. Or a metaphor.

Comment: I actually thought the extensions essentially had made '-1' a real ring, I was careful to use quotes when talking about negative rings but your explanation was really interesting. And thinking about IOMMU and DMA the other day for your question prompted this one! +1

Comment: @LTPCGO The VT-x extensions don't make a true ring (see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175826/165253). It just enables vmexit and the like. A task will still be CPL0 through CPL3, VM or not. It's just that for a guest, a privileged instruction will trigger a vmexit so the hypervisor can deal with it before resuming the VM. In fact, from the perspective of individual instructions, there's no difference between being in a guest or host!

Comment: @forest got it - I think this is similar to how ARM flags processes in secure and non-secure state too

Answer (score 1):

I will stay with the intel/x86 architecture for my answer, but it can probably be applied to other vendors/ring-designs.

Ring -3 is 'the computer that runs your computer', the management engine on the mainboard. So the next logical step would be to look for a chip on the motherboard that could exercise total control over the system. The only thing I can think of would be the **RAM**.

Now you might say that RAM doesnt really control anything as it's just a stupid buffer, and the RAM is directly controlled by the management engine. However, atleast [one company](https://www.upmem.com/) has been marketing their RAM with embedded microcontroller(s). It is supposedly used to off-load repetitive in-memory tasks to the controller embedded into the memory die.

If you can control the actual RAM, you can control anything in the system, possibly except the management engine if it has it's own memory. The microcontrollers on these devices must have full access to the RAM to do their work.

As for work done regarding exploits: these devices are far from being standardized, so using their special features will be done from kernel or usermode drivers. So you need vendor-specific exploits, as they will have vendor-specific drivers, to access the microcontroller on the RAM chips.

Comment: Could the same be said regarding memory controllers on CPUs?  IIRC that's how the ITL attack took place, by poisoning the CPU cache

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. There are multiple designs for protecting data from RAM, with the simplest being encryption or even register-only code execution. It's not hard to remove RAM from the TCB.

Comment: It's not hard to remove any other thing from the TCB either. You can run your computer without hypervisor, kernel or anything. It's just a lot more work and orders of magnitude more complex to do so. So this isnt really an argument, as RAM encryption/protection is not a common scenario.

Comment: RAM encryption is getting to be common with TSME (Intel) and SME (AMD).

Comment: In the presence of an "in-memory processor", RAM encryption would still be pointless. Either you leave it un-encrypted so the embedded processor can access it, or you give the decryption keys to the embedded processors.

Comment: As @markus-nm says, surely a CPU or whatever other piece of hardware can't do much if the processor sits in and directly interfaces with the RAM modules? I suppose if the decryption took place outside of the RAM though...

Comment: @LTPCGO Then sensitive computations could be done in registers only, or CAR mode could be enabled and sensitive data kept in cache. Both of those would remove RAM from the TCB but would still be vulnerable to "ring -2" exploits.

Comment: At least for me, *"a lot more work and orders of magnitude more complex to do"* = hard :)

Answer (score -1):

I do not agree that negative rings are false rings. They are quite real. Let's take -1 for example: having control of it almost guarantees having control over anything starting with 0 (with very few exceptions). Nothing unreal about it.

Here's how I see it today:

- Ring 3 - user-level
- Ring 2 - driver level (actual drivers)
- Ring 1 - driver emulation level (like for audio and IRQ software layering since Vista)
- Ring 0 - kernel level
- Ring -1 - VM level (hypervisors)
- Ring -2 - HW management systems (like iDRACs)
- Ring -3 - IME & similar HW

A ring -4 could exist if one could find a way to manipulate electrical signals to achieve a specific purpose like affecting a hardware component in such a manner that part of it's basic functions are disabled, jammed or altered. This is in theory entirely possible, but was never demonstrated in public as far as I know. It would also require specially-designed hardware.

Comment: In x86 parlance, "ring" has a very specific meaning. No negative rings exist because it is impossible for a process to run at CPL-1. The lowest it can run at is CPL0 (ring 0). When we say "ring -1" we're using a nickname for something which looks like a privilege ring but really isn't. Hypervisors are certainly real and they certainly can run more privileged than the guest, but that doesn't mean that it's running in a different ring. They're both ring 0, but VT-x support in the CPU provides a way for the hypervisor to have some level of control over the guest (vmexit on certain insns etc).

Comment: I will of course take this back and eat my hat if you can provide me with an x86 instruction which has a check `CPL < 0` in it! But such a thing just doesn't exist.

Comment: It really depends how you look at things. Of course, from a hardware x86 perspective, zero is absolute. But it really is like for particles. Take the smallest particle and it has something else even smaller in it.

Comment: There's no other way to look at things. They can be called negative protection rings as an analogy, but they absolutely _are_ false rings in that there is no "real" privilege level under zero.

Comment: I don't see it that way. Since normally, you can't do anything to a VM Host from inside a guest and you can do anything to the guest from the host including removing it from existence I'd call that a superior privilege.

Comment: Well a host can do anything it wants to the guest, although you're right that it doesn't work the other way around. The host actually allocates a memory buffer that the guest uses, and it can absolutely do whatever it wants to the guest (barring newer CPU features that protect the guest from the host to some extent). The host does have "superior" privileges but that doesn't mean it runs in a lower ring, as a ring is a very specific implementation of privilege boundaries.